# Python. How to merge two dictionaries with the same keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dicts:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
b = {'a': 2, 'd': 4, 'c': 5}
```

and i want to get:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 5}
```

i used {**a, **b} but it return:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 5, 'd': 4}
```

Help me please exclude keys from b which not in a with the simplest and fastest way.

i have python 3.7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression (take union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-take-union-of-dictionari)

Answer (score 2):

You have to filter the elements of the second `dict` first in order to not add any new elements. I got two possible solutions:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
b = {'a': 2, 'd': 4, 'c': 5}

for k,v in b.items():
    if (k in a.keys()):
        a[k] = v

print(a)
```

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
b = {'a': 2, 'd': 4, 'c': 5}

a.update([(k,v) for k, v in b.items() if k in a.keys()])

print(a)
```

Output for both:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a comprehension is easy enough:

```py
{ i : (b[i] if i in b else a[i]) for i in a }
```